# Ruby on Rails initial controller setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm getting started with Ruby on Rails and have some questions. I currently have a website that is written in Perl/HTML/Javascript, etc. My goal is to convert this website to use Rails. I'm running into a stubmling block on how to get started.

Here is the general overview of the current website:
The main page has 3 selection lists that get populated on page load (via SQL). The user can select an option from one of these lists (say a date as one of the lists stores dates). Currently, using AJAX, this calls a Perl CGI script which queries the database with the chosen date and returns a table containing the appropriate records (fills in division next to the selection lists).
There are no other pages on the website (besides a changelog) as everything happens on the main page. The selection lists do not get refreshed after each selection due to AJAX.

My question is, would I have a controller called Selection to populate the lists and another called Output to create the table of records? Does that setup makes sense?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my understanding about your requirement.

1) You have a page where there are three selection boxes

2) If a user changes any one of the selection box, then you are posting data to backend to get output based on the selection (using Perl CGI script)

The output is loaded after you get response from backend.

If my understanding is right, below are my suggestion.

**Suggestion :**

You need not to have different controllers for each action, in Rails you may have multiple action within a single controller.

Say you can name your controller and action as below

`Selection Controller` (Can have multiple actions under it as below, you can define custom names for each action in controller and add routing information in `app/config/routes.rb` file)

```
 - GenerateList
 - CustomAction1
 - CustomAction etc.,
```

EDIT :

You should not use single controller for all your actions in the website, you need to categorize
functionality and create multiple controller/actions accordingly.

Let me know if you face any difficulty in creating and running custom actions.

Comment: You're saying one controller for the entire website? I am trying to replace all Perl scripting as well so I'll be using Rails to generate the output. Would you say that would be done by **Selection Controller** as well?

Comment: Nope..
First you need to categorize the functionality in your PERL Script and Group actions under different controllers.
For example : I would integrate all the authorization action like `Signin/Signup/Logout/Remember Password` under `authorize` controller.. like wise you have to group actions. (You cannot use single controller for all the actions in the entire website)

Comment: Ok, that's what I figured. I was thinking **Selection Controller** with several actions that would create the lists. Then have the other controller in charge of reading the user's selection and creating the output (say **Output Controller**).  The user does not need to log into the website so the only point of authentication is connecting to the database to populate the lists and the output.